# Weird battery issues BLU Win HD LTE

Tags: windows-10-mobile, battery

My BLU Win HD LTE has been behaving strangely about the battery.

The battery would discharge while its plugged in and the phone would randomly restart when the battery is below 20%. Same when I plug the phone in, the battery would discharge, the phone will boot up to a certain percentage, the battery would drain from there and the phone will turn off. The same cycle continues for some time, and then the phone charges as normal.

Today, however, something different happened. I plugged in my phone at night and saw the battery at 28% this morning. Curious, I opened the battery monitoring app I noticed that the battery charged up to 100% normally, then dropped down to 40-50%, then climbed back up to 70% then again fell down to 28%(which is when I unplugged it) and all this happened when the phone was connected to a 5.2V 2.4A charger.

Its been a few hours since I woke up and I am using the phone heavily since then. Mobile hotspot on, watching youtube videos, playing graphic intensive games, and since the last 1.5 hours, the battery remains at 28% (it still is)

Any idea how to fix this???

I'm on windows 10
Build: 10.0.14393.693
Version: 1607

Comment: I have the same problem, and I am guessing it has something to do with a recent update (but don't quote me on that just yet). I have to restart my phone after leaving it plugged in, just so it will show 100 percent battery. Some nights I have left it charging overnight, and the next morning is at 1 or 0%, then I restart it, and it's at 100%. Weird.

Comment: @BLUPCB try the solution I posted... It worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this, and it has solved my battery problem. It also made the battery last a lot longer.

Optional step: Drain the battery low.

1. Turn off the Phone.
2. Take the Back Cover off. The RESET button can be located between the Power and Volume Down Buttons.
3. Press and Hold the RESET button for 30 seconds.
4. Start the Phone and let the battery drain till it's low.
5. Charge the Phone as normal to 100% (problem should be fixed).

Optional step: Repeat discharging the battery to a low %, then charging it again max for the initial "training" phase.

Source: http://forums.windowscentral.com/blu-win-hd-lte/386000-blu-win-hd-lte-weird-charging-issue-charging-but-percent-decreases-can-i-get-some-help.html

Answer (score -2):

Just put your phone in flight mode after resetting (powerkey + volume down key) and plug in to charger.

You may also download battery calibrator application from the Windows Store.